# .NET 6 console builds correctly as exe but when I pack to NuGet I get a DLL

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, nuget-package, .net-4.8

I have an old `console.exe` app that builds fine on .NET 4.8, and it packages fine as a NuGet.

Maybe this sounds odd, but the console app doubles as a library that I use in other projects. So, the nuget literally has my `console.exe` file in it, but I reference it as if it were like any other DLL and it all has worked fine for years.

Recently, I upgraded my `*.csproj` to the newer style SDK project format, so that I could support both .NET 4.8 and .NET 6.0 simultaneously:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net60-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

The build output appears to be correct, with the .exe showing up in the bin folder, for each targeted framework:

[image]

but when I go to pack the project, I notice that the NuGet only features a `*.dll` instead of the expected `*.exe` file:

[image]

I see this behavior both on my workstation, as well as the Azure CI build server.

Comment: That's pretty normal for .NET5+ projects, they compile to a .dll.  The .exe is the apphost, it does the same job as dotnet.exe